# Broadcast receiver from deep sleep to wakeup. (Just like, hey the device just woke up heres the broadcast!)

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Is there a Broadcast receiver I can use to determine that my device just woke up. My goal is to determine when are the occurrences of the wake up. I plan to graph the results in excel.

This is exactly the time which is NOT computed by SystemClock.uptimeMillis().

Note: I am familiar with AlarmManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF , but you can not specify them in manifest, and registering broadcast receivers from broadcast receiver ( say for ON_BOOT_COMPLETE ) is impossible.   You may try to register non-wakeup alarm, which will not fire when device is sleeping,  but past alarm will be fired when device is awakened.  I'm  affraid this is as close as you get to it.

Comment: Yes I understand your point in non wake alarm and screen actions. However, I am determining the wake up in between deep sleeps. Which I do not have to turn on screen. The best sample of what I am trying to accomplish is the connected standby state. I figured already the how much wake a device is doing, just by just totalUptime / elaptime. But my concern now are the different points when wake occurs so I can graph it.

Comment: With non-wakeup alarm you shall get wakeup moment with good precision. Deep sleep would be mtricky though.  BTW, it must be somewhere in the system logs?

Comment: Yes you right it is in the kernel log. And the ff are the different points/key lines of wake up "Entering suspend state LP0", "Resume caused by". However this method has 2 problems, first is I should get all the lines in the kernel log (which is hard to collect because of its limited buffer size). Second is other android device with different modification in kernel does not use the said key lines.

Comment: If there were just a way to dump "ALL" the kernel logs to other location (While the device is in the standby state) maybe I can find solution. Currently I am using non wake alarm to get the kernel logs however it is failing sometimes because of limited buffer of kernel log.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` but there is no specific wake up receiver.

if you do this I would say you could start a timer when screen off is fired and stop it when screen on it fired